sqlalchemy is returning mixed fields of table
I have model Products
class Products(Base):
    __tablename__ = "products"

    product_id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String, nullable= False)
    price = Column(Integer, nullable= False)
    description = Column(String)
    stars = Column(Integer)
    ingredients = Column(String, nullable= False)
    nutrition = Column(String, nullable= False)
    image_id = Column(Integer)

Parent method that should return object from DB
class BaseService:
    model = None
    
    @classmethod
    async def find_all(cls):
        async with async_session_maker() as session:
            query = select(cls.model)
            result = await session.execute(query)
            return result.mappings().all()
    

Service.py in Products directory, where all endpoints, model and service of the product are described.
from app.database import async_session_maker

from sqlalchemy import select
from app.products.models import Products
from app.services.base import BaseService


class ProductService(BaseService):
    model = Products

That should be return fields as described
class Products(Base):
    __tablename__ = "products"
    product_id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String, nullable= False)
    price = Column(Integer, nullable= False)
    description = Column(String)
    stars = Column(Integer)
    ingredients = Column(String, nullable= False)
    nutrition = Column(String, nullable= False)
    image_id = Column(Integer)

but its returning
Response body
  {
    "Products": {
      "name": "Apple Pie",
      "price": 500,
      "stars": 4,
      "nutrition": "Calories: 250 per slice",
      "description": "Delicious homemade apple pie",
      "product_id": 1,
      "ingredients": "Apples, sugar, flour, cinnamon",
      "image_id": null
    }
  }

In database when i enter select * from products its returning what i expect



product_id(pk)
name
price
description
stars
ingredients
nutrition
image_id




1
Apple_pie
500
Delicious homemade apple pie
4
Apples, sugar, flour, cinnamon
Calories: 250 per slice
None




Please include the relevant information in your question as text and not as a linked image - images aren't searchable, have bad accessibility, can't be copy/pasted (or diffed). It's also not clear whether the returned value is from a controller which you haven't included and what you expect the returned version to be (i.e. what the difference is).

HOw is the response generated, exactly?  Is there a pydantic model involved?

It seems like what you're getting back is the same as what's in the database? What is the actual difference you're trying to find? What is the controller endpoint and its response model?

If your concern is about the order of the fields in the response please show the structure of the table in the database as well as any response model involved.

I am concerned about the order of the fields. The table structure in the database (Postgresql) is the same as the Product class. I have used alembic migrations to create tables in the database. I used Product model to respond from the database. But then i get json response i get different fields order than product.

I use Declaritive Base from SQLalchemy to declare the base class of a model, not a pidantic model.

If you wanna get ordered record - you must use Pydantic model, or manually write mappings.
schema.py:
from pydantic import BaseModel

class ProductRead(BaseModel):
    product_id: int
    name: str
    price: int
    description: str
    stars: int
    ingredients: str
    nutrition: str
    image_id: int

